# Running testNG suites in parallel

Tags: java, testing, gradle, automated-tests, testng

I use gradle + testNG

Tests dynamically generate set XML files

As a result, there is a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="instances">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="test-suite.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="test2-suite.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

How to start parallel execution of data Suite?

The documentation has an example with maven and -suitethpoolsize

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites

Not suitable for gradle

I searched the Internet and did not find a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using a custom runner for that. Create a new test class, then create an instance of TestNG, and feed it with your suites, e.g:

```java
class TestExecutor {
    @Test
    public runTests() {
         List<String> suites = ... // Set here your xml paths

         TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
         testNg.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(suites.size());
         testNg.setTestSuites(suites);
         // you may also register your listeners here, e.g.:
         // testNg.addListener(new MyITestListener());
         testNg.run();
    }
}
```

And finally, include this only test class in your `gradle.build` file:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
    }
    include("**/TestExecutor.class")
}
```

Now Gradle will run your single test, which will trigger all your test suites in parallel.